# iphone - format specifiers

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using [this code](https://code.google.com/r/gaoyijun-plot/source/browse/UIColor-Expanded.m) from a guy

in the middle of this code, we have

```
- (NSString *)hexStringFromColor {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.6X", self.rgbHex];
}
```

This was working fine until Xcode 4.4. Now, I see this error:
**format specifies type unsigned int but the argument has type UInt32 (aka unsigned long).**

Why is Xcode complaining in 4.4 but not before? what specifier should I use?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `rgbHex` seems to be an unsigned long, the correct format specifier is `@"%0.6lX"` where `l` stands for `long`.

[List of iOS String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper Are you using the code unchanged? Some third party libraries redefine UInt32, so if you include any of those, things may blow up like this.

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper Either way, the error message says that the compiler equates UInt32 with "unsigned long", which means that you need the long form of the format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

Try `%0.6lX`, where the 'l' specifies that the following 'X' is a long instead of an int. You can also use `ll` if the value is actually a long long.

[image]